# Powershell If Statement Condition With Math Calculation

Tags: powershell

I'm currently having issues with Powershell.  This is the line that errors:

```
while($minutes -le ($total_bots/$increment)) {
```

All of the above variables are numbers.  I'm getting an error saying that it can't convert 60/5 - ($total_bots/$increment) - to a int32.  I want the math operation completed, and then the condition evaluated.  What am I missing?

Variables are declared like so:

```
[int]$minutes = 1
[int]$increment = 5
[int]$total_bots = 20
```

I didn't have the int there initially, but it still errors with it.

Comment: Could you show us where you define `$total_bots` and `$increment`?  One of the variables is not a number.

Comment: If that is how you are defining the variables, then you must be modifying them inside the loop.  When you do this, one (or both) is being set to a non-number.

Answer (score 0):

Was erroring below this after I changed them to [int].  Works now.  Thanks